yajra/laravel-oci8 does not connect with Oracle DB
I am Trying to establish connection between a laravel app and Oracle DB. I have installed Instant client for Laravel and oci8. I have also updated the oracle path in zshrc to point to oracle files.

export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3 export
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3 export
OCI_LIB_DIR=/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3 export
OCI_INC_DIR=/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3/sdk/sdk/include

. When i test the connection, i get the error

Undefined constant "Yajra\Pdo\OCI_DEFAULT"

when i run php-m i can see oci8 listed.
I am using macos Ventura.

Known Issue: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8/issues/799

Setting shell env variables generally isn't useful when using a web server.  Typically the web server will reset the environment, or use a different one. This is likely why php -m is OK, but the web server isn't. Find out where to set the variables for Laraval. Other tips: 1) LD_LIBRARY_PATH is a Linux variable, the macOS equivalent is DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. 2) But setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH generally won't help because Apple have locked down its usage. 3) Never set ORACLE_HOME with Instant Client. 4) Does Laraval really use OCI_LIB_DIR and OCI_INC_DIR?  The OCI8 driver itself doesn't use these.

Make sure you are checking php -m with the right user. Its possible that oci8 is enabled for one user and not the other
